Barbell hitting neck when doing behind the neck over headpressing
On the return path of the barbell in behind the neck overheadpress, the barbell sometimes hits my neck. Are there any cues so that I can make it so that the barbell lands perfectly back on my trap?

Is there any particular reason you’re choosing to do behind the neck in the first place?

Improving shoulder mobility @ThomasMarkov

Do you have a lack of mobility in your shoulders? And if so, why do you think behind the neck ohp is the solution?

BTN OHP is a classic shoulder mobility exercise and is a good tool to improve overhead position which many including myself consider part of healthy human function

The barbell should rest on your the base of your neck when you lower it, so that is not a problem. Perhaps you need to keep practicing until you can actually move the bar lower to your traps.
If it's hitting your neck in the middle or close to the base of your skull, perhaps you lack the mobility and flexibility in the shoulders to perform this exercise. You should then work on strengthening the rotator cuff muscles first.
Get your back straight and shoulder blades retracted to the back. Your elbows should point down and not back. Don't look up or down too much, your head should be facing straight forward to keep the natural curve in your spine.
